# Dynamic Update of Excel Chart with Delays

Tags: vba, excel, charts, wait

I read a data line from an instrument using Excel VBA.
I would like to plot the data dynamically on an Excel Active Chart, IMMEDIATELY after it has been read.
I need  to wait and read the data every 5 seconds and, in the mean time, I "sleep", either through the VBA Application.Wait command, or through the Kernel32 Sleep command.
In either case the Active Chart does NOT get updated.  The complete plot shows up only after the LAST "sleep".
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Here is the simplified code

```
Sub New_Data(indx)
Dim x As Integer

While True

    x = Read_Instrument(1)
    y = Read_Instrument(2)
    Cells(indx, 1) = x
    Cells(indx, 2) = y

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Item(1).Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Sheet1!$A$1:$A$" & indx
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Sheet1!$B$1:$B$" & indx

    indx = indx + 1
    Sleep 5000  'Use the KERNEL32 Sleep function for 5000 milliseconds
Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: We need to see some code to "guess" what is wrong with your current approach. With this few information, it seems that `Worksheet_Change` is the way to go.

Comment: Before any attempt to solve, I suggest naming your Chart object and getting a handle to it rather than activechart etc. ActiveChart can work, but your code will be easier to handle and avoids any focus issues. Also is the `Cells(indx, 1) = x` setting the values at the end each time? Again Qualify that call to Cells with  a Worksheet Object, such as `SheetCodeName.Cells(indx, 1) = x` etc.

Comment: I am very new to VBA and not familiar with all its advanced features. I would appreciate some information regarding (1) how to name and get a handle of the Chart Object and how to use its handle later and (2) how to qualify the call to Cells with a Worksheet object.  You could use the code that is posted above as an example.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Wait` and `Sleep` will keep VBA running, so the screen will not updated.
Try using `Application.OnTime`, along these lines (in a standard code module, i.e. Module1).

```
Sub refreshMyChart()
   Dim indx as long: indx = sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).offset(1)

   Cells(indx, 1) = Read_Instrument(1)
   Cells(indx, 2) = Read_Instrument(2)

   With Sheet1.ChartObjects(1).FullSeriesCollection(1)
     .XValues = "=Sheet1!$A$1:$A$" & indx
     .Values = "=Sheet1!$B$1:$B$" & indx
  End With

  ''''' Now Schedule the same routine for 5 seconds later''''''''''
  Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0,0,5), "refreshMyChart"
  ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
End Sub
```

p.s.: be aware that this data cannot grow indefinitely.. You should define some way to stop or to delete old rows to keep the number of displayed data rows reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent! Thank you very much.
I was not aware of the .OnTime construct
 Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5), "refreshMyChart"
and the fact that VBA allows recursive routines.
As for ending the loop, there is code in there, which I did not post because it was not relevant to the issue. Here it is
    If Int(current_index / nmeasure) * nmeasure > finalval Then
        MsgBox ("End of Measurement")
        Exit Sub
    End If

Thanks again.